# Syntax error when using core-header-panel with Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to use Polymer's `core-header-panel` to get used to the framework. I've tried to set up a basic page using this index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src='/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js'></script>
  <link rel='import' href='/components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html'>
</head>
<body unresolved>
  <core-header-panel>

  </core-header-panel>
</body>
</html>
```

(`components` is a symlink to `bower_components` - eliminating the symlink does not cause any difference so it's not the symlink).

I am getting the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`.

This only occurs when I have `core-header-panel.html`'s import in my `head` - having something in the body makes no difference. The error appears to be whilst parsing `core-header-panel.html`. I am using ChromeCanary 44.0 x64 on a Windows platform, although the problem can be replicated in Chrome 42.0.

I've done a brief dig through the code but I do not understand Polymer enough to work out where the issue is coming from; all I know is that it is occurring inside `Polymer.Bind._addAnnotatedListener`. Here's a complete stacktrace (for some reason I cannot copy+paste the entire stack trace through Chrome dev tools).

Any help with this basic example is greatly appreciated. I haven't added any of my own code, this is just reusing components that are already there.

[image: StackTrace of error]

**bower.json**

- `polymer` version `0.8.0`.
- `paper-elements` version `0.5.5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to bower version mismatch. Oops. Polymer was using 0.8.0, but Paper Elements required 0.5.5